# When I generate PBF vector tiles with geoserver, generating so many zero size files.How can I delete them after geoserver generating them immediately?

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles

When I use GeoServer GWC generating PBF vector tiles, generating so many zero size files.

[image]

[image]

I can delete them with Linux command `"find ./ -type f -size 0c|xargs -n 1 rm -f"` when this level seeding end.

Executing this Linux delete command is so slow, which costs more time than GeoServer GWC seeding.

This deleting method costs time is too long.

Can I set GeoServer configuration or modify GeoServer source code to realize a new delete method which I can delete them after GeoServer generating them immediately rather than I need delete them using Linux command?

I have built GeoServer 2.18.3 version source code in Eclipse. If I modify source code I can compile GeoServer jar files. I can start GeoServer service with Eclipse to test:

[image]

Can you give me some clues or methods?

Comment: why do you need to delete them?

Comment: Linux inode number is limiting.There are too many 0 size files which account for 97.64% of all tiles consuming a lot of linux inode.Bigger than level 15 ,tile number is so huge.

Comment: add more `inodes` then or include less empty space in your map

Comment: I use the method of adding inodes number some days ago.I do not think it is a good solution.Adding inodes needs format the disk,and other inconvenient aspects.You say include less empty space. I do not know the good and quick method to decrease empty space ,can you tell me the good method ? I think it is a good idea we delete it when geoserver generate 0 size file ,but I am not familiar to the geoserver source code.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to clean up the zero-sized tiles. They also act as a marker that the tile has been generated, removing them will cause the server to try and re-create them.

One possible approach is to apply a mask over the data, so that generation of the tiles won't even be attempted in those areas. Unfortunately the documentation on how to use these filters is basically missing, you'll have to go into the GeoWebCache source code and figure out if these filters  still work, and how to use them. For reference

- https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/configuration/layers/requestfilters.html
- https://sourceforge.net/p/geowebcache/mailman/message/31616093/

Comment: I use the seeding result tiles to publish a vector tiles service we call it WMTS.These tiles are generated beforehand.If I delete the zero-sized tiles,it will not cause the server to try and re-create them.Bigger than level 15 the number of zero-sized files is too huge to bear by Linux system.GWC seeding generates file one by one,why can we delete the zero-sized files when the file have generated?I think RequestFilter is used in htttp request,but my scene is WMTS like tomcat file service.It is only a file service rather than generating tiles.

Comment: What you're looking for is not there, but GWC is open source, feel free to add it, and contribute the improvement back to the community, using a pull request.